# Excel VBA code breaks after saving document. (ActiveCell.Address & ActiveCell.Name)

Tags: excel, vba, save

I have the following script to copy range of the active cell to clipboard and it works fine untill I save the document (without closing it) after which it breaks:

```
Sub getCellSheetAndAddress()
Dim Sheet As String
Dim Address As String
Dim myData As DataObject

Sheet = ActiveSheet.Name
Address = ActiveCell.Address

Set myData = New DataObject
myData.SetText (Sheet + "!" + Address)
myData.PutInClipboard
Set myData = Nothing

End Sub
```

I can use this macro to get cell range and then paste it but when I save the excel and run the macro again what is being pasted into cell are two blank squares rather than the cell location.

What is the reason behind it and how to solve it?

Many thanks

Comment: It's a bug in the dataobject on versions of windows from W8 onwards when file explorer is open. It's better to use API calls or other alternatives.

Comment: Try renaming your variables.  Sheet and Address are both terms that are used in VBA code.

Comment: It works in my Office 2019 64-bit. Even if I close Excel and paste it into Notepad or again into Excel. What does *"and run the macro again"* mean? Could you share the code where you're pasting it?

Comment: @Myykro changing the variables names didn't help

Comment: @VBasic2008 when I close the program the problem is fixed. It goes like this: I go to cell A1 and run the script, then I go to some other cell and I can paste 'Sheet1!$A$1', but then if I press save button and go to cell say A2 and run script, when I paste from clipboard in another cell i get two square symbols

Comment: @Rory thanks this seems to be an issue, closing file explorer windows stops this from happening, thank you buddy. I am quite new to vba what API or alternatives are you refering to? what should I search for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use functions like this:

```
Function SetClipBoardText(ByVal Text As Variant) As Boolean
    CreateObject("htmlfile").ParentWindow.ClipboardData.SetData "Text", Text
End Function

Function GetClipBoardText() As String
    On Error Resume Next
    GetClipBoardText = CreateObject("htmlfile").ParentWindow.ClipboardData.getData("Text")
End Function
```

or look at the `SetClipBoardData` and `GetClipBoardData` API functions.